# Filter based on few conditions from another object

Tags: javascript, filter

Hello I wish to filter array of object based on my state, I have several properties in my filters object and I wish to return array which fill these requirements. So far I managed to do it on only one condition. I know why, it is because of my ifs but I don't really know how to code it to apply to all conditons like for example in case of false in danger and services, I wish only to return object which type is relax

```js
const markers = [{
    name: "one",
    type: "danger"
  },
  {
    name: "two",
    type: "relax"
  },
  {
    name: "three",
    type: "service"
  },
  {
    name: "four",
    type: "danger"
  },
]

const [filters, setFilters] = useState({
  danger: true,
  relax: true,
  services: true,
});

const filtered = markers((el) => {
  if (!filters.danger) return el.type !== "danger";
  if (!filters.relax) return el.type !== "relax";
  if (!filters.services) return el.type !== "services";
  return el;
});
```

in Case of danger and services set to false, I wish to have output

```
const markers = [
{name: "two", type:"relax"},
]
```

Comment: Add your sample data, and wished result.

Comment: @ikiK I added it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a quick filter() function:

```js
const markers = [{
    name: "one",
    type: "danger"
  },
  {
    name: "two",
    type: "relax"
  },
  {
    name: "three",
    type: "service"
  },
  {
    name: "four",
    type: "danger"
  },
];

const filters = {
  danger: false,
  relax: false,
  service: true,
};

const shouldIncludeMarker = ({type}) => filters[type];
console.log(markers.filter(shouldIncludeMarker));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [filter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
const markers = [
  {name: "one", type:"danger"},
  {name: "two", type:"relax"},
  {name: "three", type:"service"},
  {name: "four", type:"danger"}
];

// Filter your data as you wish
const filtered = markers.filter(item => {
  if(item.type == "relax") return true;
  if(item.type == "service") return true;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Filter wrapper

```js
const markers = [
  {name: "one", type:"danger"},
  {name: "two", type:"relax"},
  {name: "three", type:"service"},
  {name: "four", type:"danger"}
];

// Create wrapper function
// to pass parameters to filter
const fltr = (array, types) => array.filter(item => types.indexOf(item.type) > -1);

// Test 1
console.log(fltr(markers, ["danger"]));

// Test 2
console.log(fltr(markers, ["relax", "service"]));
```

Comment: ok but what if I change values in filters then it won't work anymore... For example if I wish to return danger and relax and filter services